# Creating an Android "remote" app for Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, wireless, remote, keyboard, android

Similar to how you can control XBMC/Kodi/Raspbmc through the Android app ["Yatse XBMC/Kodi Remote Control"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree&hl=en_GB).

Can anyone confirm whether either a.) there is something out there for Raspbian, or b.) if it's technically feasible to create an Android app that you could use to connect to the raspberry pi, and navigate/type input through the phone app, to Raspbian?

Essentially, I currently have my RPi with Raspbian set up, wireless connection, connected to my TV through HDMI. I then want to be able to wirelessly type on my phone, and for the text to transmit wirelessly to the Pi and to come up on the TV. I want to connect my **wired** keyboard, via an OTG cable, in to my Nexus 5, and then be able to open an app on my Android phone that allows me to type. This means that I'd be able to connect my wired keyboard to my phone, and then type using the wired keyboard which would wirelessly transmit through the Nexus, to the RPi. This can seemingly be done over SSH quite easily but I want it to actually come up on the command line. I can't seem to Google my way to a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JuiceSSH on android (or any other ssh client, I'm not particularly recommending that one) to ssh into the pi.  You can't forward the GUI that way though, it would be CLI only.

> if it's technically feasible to create an Android app that you could use to connect to the raspberry pi

Sure, it's totally feasible.  It's just a lot of work.  I've thought before about doing something that uses the kernel input event interface so you could use the phone's touchscreen to move a mouse pointer remotely.  You need some kind of custom TCP server on the pi and a corresponding client on the phone.  The server could do pretty much anything.  Just again, it's a lot of work and as far as I know no one has done it in a broad, general purpose sense.  I'm sure there is all kinds of *specialized* Android -> linux device software out there, but that won't do you any good.

On the linux side, what you are interested in is [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput); this involves some native C `ioctl()` calls but there are [python bindings](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as well.  You can simulate various HID (human interface device) events such as key presses, mouse clicks, etc.

Comment: Is that what the Yatse XBMX remote will be doing? Yep, I've managed to do the above by using JuiceSSH and then hooking up the keyboard to my Nexus with the OTG cable, but my (seemingly distant) dream would be to be able to do it straight to the pi terminal so that I can use the TV as my screen whilst typing. Is there any chance you could point me in the direction of where to start? I've been looking for a pet project to start, but I've not come across many problems recently - this seems like a good one to try! No problem if not, appreciate the response! Thanks.

Comment: I've added a brief last paragraph about that.  Obviously you need some java skills for the android side.

Comment: Thanks - will have to see how my memory of Java/Android SDK holds up from Uni!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Good place to start.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stochastictechnologies.tungsten&hl=en